# Q_OBJECT, SLOT which is pointer on function

Tags: qt, function-pointers, signals-slots

I can`t declare *Q_OBJECT* which has *SLOT* what *is pointer on function* because MOC is unable to compile it.
Can you offer me correct implementation?

```
public slots:
    void (*refMoveMethod) (Compound_object& object);
...

QObject::connect(someTimer, SIGNAL(timout()), this, SLOT(refMoveMethos));
```

Comment: Do you want to create a slot that has a function pointer as an argument?  Or use a function pointer in place of a `SLOT(..)` command in a `connect(..)` call?  Please add an example of you would *like* to do.

Comment: public slots:
 void (*refMoveMethod) (Compound_object& object);
    QObject::connect(someTimer, SIGNAL(timout()), this, SLOT      (refMoveMethos))

Comment: If you want to inherit from QObject, and use the Q_OBJECT macro, to create custom signals/slots then you need to run qmake in creator first. If you want a SLOT, what takes a function pointer, then i have no idea.

Comment: Actually not only qmake, but: qmake -project; qmake; nmake. Yes I want a SLOT what takes a function pointer and I think I gave you the example in which my intention is quite clear.

Comment: No it isn't.  In `public slots:` you have declared a pointer to a function that takes a `Compound_object&`, you cannot do this as only methods can be inside the `public slots` area.  Qt signals can only be connected to signals or slots, but the function pointed at is free therefore cannot be a member of a class, and therefore cannot be a part of `QObject` meta-object system - so even if you planned on switching the 'target' method at runtime (presumably why you are asking this), it wouldn't connect.  Maybe you should tell exactly what you are trying to achieve with this?

Comment: @cbamber85 That I am going to do: I have BUILDER(pattern) which create instances of class compound_object and configure them. One of options of configuration is ability to choose function which is responsible for modifying some object`s characteristics (move it), it is choosen from namespace in which compound_object is declared.

As object moves with some frequency I need to connect timer which invokes movement method selected by BUILDER during configuration.

Comment: Previously I implemented this idea by defining method in compound_object what called pointer on function(this method was declared as SLOT) what was also member of compound_object and this worked fine. But now I am refactoring my code and whant to make it more efficient and trying to reimplement it.